FCM HTTP v1 accessToken working on localhost but not on production
I am using FCM HTTP v1 API with below code, It's working fine on localhost, and accessToken is getting successfully. But after deployment, it doesn't works on server, getting timeout issue every time (Error: socket hang up on postman from server url). Could you please help out in this. Is there any internal FCM APIs endpoints that need to whitelist on our server? If yes, then could you please provide all internal FCM APIs endpoints that is breaking due to server fireball.
Below snippet I am using to get accessToken from FCM HTTP v1
const { GoogleAuth } = require("google-auth-library");

const auth = new GoogleAuth({
      credentials: {
        client_email: CLIENT_EMAIL,
        private_key: PRIVATE_KEY,
      },
      scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"],
});

const client = await auth.getClient();
const accessToken = await client.getAccessToken();
return accessToken.token;



Currently I am using legacy FCM API but that support will removed post 20th June, so we need to upgrade on immediate basis in our project otherwise it will break to our users on prod but facing this issue from long time. Can someone from FCM team quickly respond over this.

I have posted my answer here, it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78951006/5528827
